# How to open two modals at the same time in react.js using MUi or tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog, tailwind-css, mo

I want to implement the same functionality as the modals we see when we click on share some item on Google docs or Google drive..like the picture below please guide me on how can I implement that and point me out if there is an example on codepen or any other code sharing websites.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what Google Drive does, is wrap these "two modals" in the same element, and this element is THE modal.

So, there are no two modals, actually is just one, with two elements inside.

[image: google drive screenshot]

You can check this example, with two elements inside the modal wrap
https://play.tailwindcss.com/zJzC184qdI